# How to add specific index values to enum's like enum('a'=5,'b',c'=20) in SQL. Is there any to do this

Tags: mysql, sql, enums

I want to assign specific index values in enum's in mysql. Like enum('a' = 5, 'b', 'c' =20) in mysql.

Is there any way to do this in mysql.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this DA article](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51850/using-an-enum-as-part-of-an-index-definition).  If your enum column has less than 10 unique values, then it may not be worth putting an index on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not allow you to specify the exact mapping, it is basically mapped in order.  This is described on the type page:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/enum.html